# LaTeX3 dynamic generation of \prg_new_conditional

Tags: expl3, latex3, package-writing

I have multiple pieces of redundant LaTeX3 code that creates new conditionals:

```latex
\bool_if:nT
  { \cs_if_free_p:N \mypkg_if_package_loaded_p:n &&
    \cs_if_free_p:N \mypkg_if_package_loaded_T:n &&
    \cs_if_free_p:N \mypkg_if_package_loaded_F:n &&
    \cs_if_free_p:N \mypkg_if_package_loaded_TF:n }
  {
    \prg_new_conditional:Nnn \mypkg_if_package_loaded:n { p, T, F, TF }
      {
        \use:c { @ifpackageloaded } { #1 }
          { \prg_return_true: }
          { \prg_return_false: }
      }
  }
```

I want to replace the first code with something more concise, like the following:

```latex
\cs_new_protected:Npn \mypkg_def_if:Nn #1#2
  {
    \clist_new:N \l_mypkg_cond_clist
    \clist_map_inline:nn { p, T, F, TF }
      {
        \bool_if:nT { \cs_if_free_p:N #1:##1 }
          { \clist_put_right:Nn \l_mypkg_cond_clist { #1 } }
      }
    \prg_new_conditional:Nnn #2:n { \l_mypkg_cond_clist }
      {
        \use:c { #2 } { ##1 }
          { \prg_return_true: }
          { \prg_return_false: }
      }
  }

\mypkg_def_if:Nn \mypkg_if_package_loaded { @ifpackageloaded }
\mypkg_def_if:Nn \mypkg_if_package_with { @ifpackagewith }
\mypkg_def_if:Nn \mypkg_if_class_loaded { @ifclassloaded }
\mypkg_def_if:Nn \mypkg_if_class_with { @ifclasswith }
```

To solve it I'm trying to follow this structure:

1. Create a new clistA
2. Iterate over {p, T, F, TF}
3. For each element, check if function + element is available with `\cs_if_free`
4. If available, add it to clistB
5. Create a conditional with arg1 and clistB
6. Use arg2 as a control sequence
7. Attempt to disambiguate the arguments

Any feedback appreciated!

Comment: I'm not sure what `\cs_if_free:…` would be needed for, as you seem to be writing package code and *you* are in charge of what's defined.

Comment: That's a good point! Since I'll use it as a helper function I'd want to safeguard myself from defining already existing conditionals.

Comment: @Neveda don't. It's your package and you should use a unique module-prefix for it (`mypgk` in your MWE). If you use `\prg_new_conditional:Npnn` you'll get an error that the conditional is already defined, and if it is you can just remove the duplicate definition from your sources.

Comment: I see and understand your concerns. The code is already in place and serves its purpose well, acting the same way `\ProvideDocumentCommand` does. I'm looking for a way to make it shorter and DRY.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can't see the need for `\cs_if_free:NTF`. You're developing a package and if, by mistake, you try redefining an already defined conditional *in your own namespace*, you'll be welcome with an error message that says so. In this case just remove the faulty piece of code and go on.

This is the reason why a prefix specific to a package is recommended: you're, the package author, are completely responsible for the functions and variables using that prefix.

Actually, with your `\bool_if:nT` you're sweeping the problem under the carpet. Suppose you have already defined `\mypkg_if_foo:nTF` in your big package and at some later time you forget having done so and deem `foo` good for some other conditional. If you use your `\bool_if:nT` strategy, your new conditional will *not* be defined and the older function will still be used at each call of `\mypkg_if_foo:nTF`. Are you sure you wouldn't prefer an error message, so you can realize the mistake and choose a new name? I would.

Using `\bool_if:nTF` and a warning in the “false” branch would help, but I see no advantage.

Last, but not least, definitions of similar functions should not be scattered among the package, but kept near to each other, for easier maintenance. Thus you'll have a section

```
% define conditionals emulating the LaTeX kernel pseudoconditionals
\prg_new_conditional:Nnn \mypkg_if_package_loaded:n { p, T, F, TF }
 {
  \use:c { @ifpackageloaded } { #1 } { \prg_return_true: } { \prg_return_false: }
 }
```

Now we can write syntactic sugar for defining such conditional “at once”.

```
% define conditionals emulating the LaTeX kernel pseudoconditionals
\cs_new_protected:Nn \__mypkg_define_kernel_conditional:Nn
 {
  \prg_new_conditional:Nnn #1 { p,T,F,TF }
   {
    \use:c { #2 } { \prg_return_true: } { \prg_return_false: }
   }
 }
\__mypkg_define_kernel_conditional:Nn \mypkg_if_package_loaded:n { @ifpackageloaded }
\__mypkg_define_kernel_conditional:Nn \mypkg_if_package_with:n { @ifpackagewith }
\__mypkg_define_kernel_conditional:Nn \mypkg_if_class_loaded:n { @ifclassloaded }
\__mypkg_define_kernel_conditional:Nn \mypkg_if_class_with:n { @ifclasswith }
```

If you really want to use your `\bool_if:nT` strategy, then

```
\cs_new_protected:Nn \__mypkg_define_kernel_conditional:nn
 {
  \bool_if:nT
   {
    \cs_if_free_p:c {mypkg_if_#1_p:n} &&
    \cs_if_free_p:c {mypkg_if_#1:nT &&
    \cs_if_free_p:c {mypkg_if_#1:nF &&
    \cs_if_free_p:c {mypkg_if_#1:nTF
   }
   {
    \prg_new_conditional:cnn {mypkg_if_#1:n} { p,T,F,TF }
     {
      \use:c { #2 } { \prg_return_true: } { \prg_return_false: }
     }
   }
 }
\__mypkg_define_kernel_conditional:nn {package_loaded} { @ifpackageloaded }
\__mypkg_define_kernel_conditional:nn {package_with} { @ifpackagewith }
\__mypkg_define_kernel_conditional:nn {class_loaded} { @ifclassloaded }
\__mypkg_define_kernel_conditional:nn {class_with} { @ifclasswith }
```

Comment: I like this one the most, thank you!

Answer (score 3):

I still think that your package is your namespace, hence your responsibility. As long as this isn't used via a user-interface to set up some internal auxiliaries I'd not advise using it and instead simply do a `\cs_new_eq:Nc \nevada_if_package_loaded:nTF { @ifpackageloaded }` to get the conditional if you absolutely need a package name for a 2e-macro.

The following might be more complicated than it has to be, but does what you want:

```
\documentclass{article}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\clist_new:N \l__nevada_variants_clist
\tl_new:N \l__nevada_cs_parts_tl
\tl_new:N \l__nevada_arg_forwarded_tl
\str_new:N \l__nevada_cs_base_str
\str_new:N \l__nevada_cs_args_str
\int_new:N \l__nevada_arg_count_int
\msg_new:nnn { nevada } { missing-colon }
  { Function~ name~ #1~ misses~ a~ colon. }
\cs_new_protected:Npn \__nevada_split_cs:N #1
  {
    \tl_set:Nx \l__nevada_cs_parts_tl { \cs_split_function:N #1 }
    \bool_if:nF { \exp_last_unbraced:No \use_iii:nnn \l__nevada_cs_parts_tl }
      {
        \msg_error:nnn { nevada } { missing-colon } {#1}
        \prg_break:
      }
    \str_set:Nx \l__nevada_cs_base_str
      { \exp_last_unbraced:No \use_i:nnn  \l__nevada_cs_parts_tl }
    \str_set:Nx \l__nevada_cs_args_str
      { \exp_last_unbraced:No \use_ii:nnn \l__nevada_cs_parts_tl }
  }
\cs_new:Npn \__nevada_cs_base:
  { \exp_last_unbraced:No \use_i:nnn \l__nevada_cs_parts_tl }
\cs_new_protected:Npn \__nevada_provide_conditional:NNnn #1#2#3#4
  {
    \__nevada_split_cs:N #2
    \clist_clear:N \l__nevada_variants_clist
    \clist_map_inline:nn {#3}
      {
        \cs_if_exist:cF
          {
            \l__nevada_cs_base_str
            \str_if_eq:nnT {##1} { p } { _p }
            : \l__nevada_cs_args_str
            \str_if_eq:nnF {##1} { p } { \tl_to_str:n {##1} }
          }
          { \clist_put_right:Nn \l__nevada_variants_clist {##1} }
      }
    \clist_if_empty:NF \l__nevada_variants_clist
      {
        \exp_args:NNe #1 #2
          { \clist_use:Nn \l__nevada_variants_clist { , } }
          {#4}
      }
    \prg_break_point:
  }
\cs_new_protected:Npn \nevada_provide_conditional:Nnn
  { \__nevada_provide_conditional:NNnn \prg_new_conditional:Nnn }
\cs_new_protected:Npn \nevada_provide_protected_conditional:Nnn
  { \__nevada_provide_conditional:NNnn \prg_new_protected_conditional:Nnn }

\cs_new_protected:Npn \nevada_provide_all_conditionals:Nn #1
  { \nevada_provide_conditional:Nnn #1 { TF, T, F, p } }
\cs_new_protected:Npn \nevada_provide_all_protected_conditionals:Nn #1
  { \nevada_provide_protected_conditional:Nnn #1 { TF, T, F } }
\cs_new_protected:Npn \__nevada_provide_conditional_alias:NNN #1#2#3
  {
    \__nevada_split_cs:N #2
    \int_set:Nn \l__nevada_arg_count_int { \str_count:N \l__nevada_cs_args_str }
    \tl_clear:N \l__nevada_arg_forwarded_tl
    \int_step_inline:nn { \l__nevada_arg_count_int }
      { \tl_put_right:Nn \l__nevada_arg_forwarded_tl { {######1} } }
    \exp_args:NNe #1 #2
      {
        \exp_not:N #3 \l__nevada_arg_forwarded_tl
          \exp_not:N \prg_return_true:
          \exp_not:N \prg_return_false:
      }
    \prg_break_point:
  }
\cs_new_protected:Npn \nevada_provide_conditional_alias:NN
  {
    \__nevada_provide_conditional_alias:NNN \nevada_provide_all_conditionals:Nn
  }
\cs_new_protected:Npn \nevada_provide_protected_conditional_alias:NN
  {
    \__nevada_provide_conditional_alias:NNN
      \nevada_provide_all_protected_conditionals:Nn
  }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \nevada_provide_protected_conditional_alias:NN { Nc }

\nevada_provide_protected_conditional_alias:Nc
  \nevada_if_package_loaded:n
  { @ifpackageloaded }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}
\texttt{graphicx} is
\ExplSyntaxOn
\nevada_if_package_loaded:nF {graphicx} { not~ }
\ExplSyntaxOff
loaded.

You
\ExplSyntaxOn
\nevada_if_package_loaded:nTF {xcolor} { did } { should } ~
\ExplSyntaxOff
load \texttt{xcolor}.
\end{document}
```

Comment: This one is amazing! It has a lot of work into it, thank you lots!